# How to bind values in formview using different possible values

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have two different tables one `telephone` with these columns `[tel_id],[client_id],[tel_no],[tel_type_id],[details_type_id],[sort_no]` where `tel_id` is the pk n client_id is fk
 and another table `telephone_id` with columns `[tel_type_id],[tel_type_lib_fr] ,[tel_type_lib_en].`
I dont know how to bind and display the telephone number to the formview according to the type.
say if its type 1 then landline ; 2 _ mobile n if 3 fax

there's also another table called client where client_id is the pk. i've made a join in between these and a few more tables from the same db.

Thanks.

Hi all after some research i managed to do this within the inner join itself....something like this
LEFT OUTER JOIN TELEPHONE AS LANDLINE ON CLIENT.client_id = LANDLINE.client_id AND LANDLINE.tel_type_id = 1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TELEPHONE AS MOBILE ON CLIENT.client_id = MOBILE.client_id AND MOBILE.tel_type_id = 2 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TELEPHONE AS FAX ON CLIENT.client_id = FAX.client_id AND FAX.tel_type_id = 3
and in the select it was  LANDLINE.tel_no AS Landline, MOBILE.tel_no AS Mobile, FAX.tel_no AS Fax ,
later i bound it to the itemtemplate
tel_no:
                '/> 
                
landline:
                '/>
                
Fax:
                ' />

and works like charm. thx for all who took time to read :)

Answer (score 0):

simple use inner join to get data and use if..then..end in SP so you can get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal 
       ID="literal1" 
       runat="server"
       Text='<%# Eval("tel_type_id").ToString() == "1" ? "Landline" : 
             Eval("tel_type_id").ToString() == "2" ? "Mobile" : "Fax" %>'
     />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: When i included this within the itemtemplate of the form view i got the string value telling if its a landline/fax/mobile but the value of the column is missing. should i include something like Text='<%# Bind("tel_no") %> to get the value after the string? thanks